# function works with apply, but not mutate R seeking deeper understanding

Tags: r, dplyr

It seems that mutate and apply work differently and I'd like some insight. First I'll start with an example:

```
df = data.frame(base = as.character(letters), dat1 = runif(26), dat2 = runif(26))
df = df %>% mutate(path = paste0(base,'.txt'))

test_function = function(path){
    print(length(path))
    if(exists(path)){
        table = read.table(path)
        return(mean(table[,1]))
    } else {
        return(NA)
    }
}

# This prints 26 ones
df$val = unlist(
    lapply(
        df$path,
        test_function
    )
)

# This prints 26
df = df %>% mutate(val = test_function(path))
```

Both functions produce the same result, however they print different values.

I seems that with apply, we are calling the function 26 times, each time passing a single path to the function.

When using mutate, it seems that we are calling the function a single time. passing it a vector of paths.

My question comes down to this. When I am writing my real function. do I need to worry about these differences? I just called a function from a library, where the library checks the dimensions of the argument passed, and it threw an error with mutate.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I've read a little about vectorized code. Is an example of that?

Comment: mutate requires vectorized functions. You can vectorize most scalar functions using `Vectorize`

Comment: Your `if` `else` code will only run once for the first value of `df$path` - see the warning message if you try something like `x <- 1:10; if(x < 10) print("yay!")`. `lapply` just loops the `if` `else` over each value in `df$path` so you get 26 distinct results instead of just 1 - just like `x <- 1:10; lapply(x, function(v) if(v < 10) print("yay!") )`

Answer (score 0):

I found the comments by @yeedle and @thelatemail sufficient to answer my question. in addition check out this [link](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2014/4/16/vectorization-in-r--why.html) describing the reasons for vectorized code. (Its a great read)

To summarize their comments:

`apply` does not try to vectorize the operation, whereas the `dplyr` function `mutate` requires vectorized functions. Most functions can be vectorized using Vectorize.

In the example above, the `if else` code will only run once for the first value of `df$path` for a vectorized function, but with `lapply` it just loops the `if else` over each value in `df$path` so you get 26 distinct results instead of just one.

Comment: Good stuff. I think on SO, it is preferred to put the answer in the answer rather than just pointing to the comments. If you felt like it, a brief summary of the comments and/or link would be a nice gift back to the community.